# i don't know why i am getting errors , i'm student and i did like my teacher but he execute it and mine getting error in my SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysql-error-1064

```
create table salesman
(
salesman_id  int not null,
 [name]    varchar(50),
 [city] varchar(50),
 commission  float,
constraint pk_salesman_id primary key (salesman_id)

)
insert into salesman
(salesman_id,[name],[city],commission) values ('5001','James Hoog','New York', 0.15),

([salesman_id],[Name],[City], Commission) values ('5002','Nail Knite','Paris',0.13),

(salesman_id,[name],[city],commission) values ('5005','Pit Alex','London',0.11),

(salesman_id,[name],[city],commission) values ('5006','Mc Lyon','Paris',0.14),

(salesman_id,[name],[city],commission) values ('5003','Lauson Hen',' ',0.12),

(salesman_id ,[name],[city],commission) values ('5007','Paul Adam''Rome',0.13),
```

Comment: Is this (Microsoft) SQL Server or MySQL? Please edit your question to remove the incorrect tag.

Comment: Did your teacher repeat `([salesman_id],[Name],[City], Commission) values` for every record to be inserted?

Comment: Please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify the columns followed by the 'values' keyword each time, plus you have a comma at the end of your statement, which is invalid syntax.

Additionally, you're missing a comma on one of your insert statements:

```
('5007','Paul Adam''Rome',0.13)
```

In between 'Paul Adam' and 'Rome'.

Please try and format your code better as well, it helps it become more readable to those you're asking questions to.

The code you want is:

```
CREATE TABLE salesman (
    [salesman_id] int not null, 
    [name] varchar(50), 
    [city] varchar(50), 
    [commission] float, 
    constraint [pk_salesman_id] primary key (salesman_id)
) 

INSERT INTO salesman 
    ([salesman_id],
    [name],
    [city],
    commission) 
VALUES 
    ('5001','James Hoog','New York', 0.15),
    ('5002','Nail Knite','Paris',0.13),
    ('5005','Pit Alex','London',0.11),
    ('5006','Mc Lyon','Paris',0.14),
    ('5003','Lauson Hen',' ',0.12),
    ('5007','Paul Adam','Rome',0.13);
```

Here is the working code:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1436d3b2f4102fb6f423a1a6461b746